# What will happen to nuclear power stations / reactors if chain reaction suddenly stops to provide energy?

Tags: science-based, nuclear, nuclear-power

What will happen to reactors if nuclear fission chain reactions in some specific areas will just stop working?

Other types of nuclear phenomena (ones with gamma rays, positrons,etc) are still in effect, just not chain reactions with neutrons.

Comment: Part of it depends on how the chain reaction is being suppressed. Are free neutrons decaying too quickly? That would likely mean some other decays happen more easily. Are the relevant isotopes bound more tightly, so they can absorb a neutron without it inducing fission? Then there's probably isotopes that you can produce in those areas that weren't stable before, and which would be unstable if removed. This could cut out a lot of the decay heat you'd otherwise see.

Comment: This would be just like pulling out the moderator rods. High energy neutrons have a smaller collision cross-section, so they are a lot less effective at triggering other decays. The reactor stops working and cools down.

Answer (score 5):

Nuclear fission is what gives a nuclear reactor the "juice" to produce energy. With it stopping, the "juice" would be gone and you would be left with a hot core which would slowly cool down to the temperature supported by the remaining nuclear phenomena.

Probably the remaining thermal energy during the transient would be sufficient to power some generator with a way lower power than the nominal power of the nuclear reactor.

Basically what happens is the same as what happens when a real nuclear reactor goes into safety mode with the procedure called [SCRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scram), with all control bars inserted to stop the fission.

> As a result, once the reactor has been scrammed, the reactor power will drop significantly almost instantaneously. A small fraction (about 0.65%) of neutrons in a typical power reactor comes from the radioactive decay of a fission product. These delayed neutrons, which are emitted at lower velocities, will limit the rate at which a nuclear reactor will shut down.

> Not all of the heat in a nuclear reactor is generated by the chain reaction that a scram is designed to stop. For a reactor that is scrammed after holding a constant power level for an extended period (greater than 100 hrs), about 7% of the steady-state power will remain after initial shutdown due to fission product decay that cannot be stopped. For a reactor that has not had a constant power history, the exact percentage is determined by the concentrations and half-lives of the individual fission products in the core at the time of the scram.

> The power produced by decay heat decreases as the fission products decay, but it is large enough that failure to remove decay heat may cause the reactor core temperature to rise to dangerous levels and has caused nuclear accidents, including the nuclear accidents at Three Mile Island and Fukushima I.